# Split String based on comma and concate into query String in java

Tags: java, string, delimiter, string-concatenation

I have a String which contains values separated by comma .Now as per my need i have to split the String by comma (,) and concatenate the Substring into query string  but i am not able to get the idea ..here is my code...I need to split the String and concatenate into the query..

Extension contains the values like 1111,2341,5028

```
String extension = request.getParameter("extension");
System.out.println(extension);
if(extension!=""){
//here i need to concate the substring into query delimited by comma.
query=query.concat("'").concat(" and extension='"+extension);

}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Compare strings with `.equals`, not `==` (likewise for `!=`). Other than that: your question is fairly unclear. What's a sample input and the corresponding expected output?

Comment: Can you show how would be the output ?

Comment: If this is a database query, you'd be better off using `PreparedStatement`

Comment: [Beware of the Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Here the `'` placed at `.. ' and extension=' .. `, shouldn't it be `... and extension = ' ... '`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use split method and get the substrings one by one

```
for (String ext: extension.split(",")){
   // your code goes here
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
{
        String myInput = "1111,2341,5028";
        String[] splitted = myInput.split(",");

        String query = " Select * from Table where "; // something like Select * from Table where 
        StringBuilder concanatedquery= new StringBuilder();

        for (String output : splitted) 
        {
            concanatedquery.append(" extension = '" + output.replace("'", "''") +"'  AND ");    //replace confirms that no failure will be there if splited string contains ' and if this splitted string are numeric then remove 'replace' clause and char ' after extension = ' and before "' AND"            
        }

        query = query + concanatedquery.substring(0, concanatedquery.length() - 4); //4 characters are removed as 'AND  ' will be extra at the end.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use StringBuilder class to concatenate and build the SQL query, which has append method.

```
String [] parts = originalString.split(",");
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(String str: parts){
 builder.append(str);
builder.append(" ");
}
return builder.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could Split the string Like this

```
String str = "1111,2341,5028";
String filenameArray[] =  str.split("\\,");
// ACCESS THE ARRAY POSITION LIKE filenameArray[0],filenameArray[1]  AND SO ON
```

Comment: @WarrenFaith ... sory for posting this here ... actualy ... i need to ask something .... is it possible to send the app request to to a non-friend user on facebook..